# How to make a GET to a certain URL every 5 mins in Laravel

Tags: php, python, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel. I'm trying to make a GET to a certain URL (http://localhost/user/check_token) every 5 mins.

I'm thinking:

- Create a route http://localhost/user/check_token
- Write a Python script to make a GET to that route
- Configure a cron job to trigger that script every 5 mins

But I'm curious if we can achieve this in Laravel itself.

Can we declare a route and make it self executed, or something like that?

Is my Python solution is the best practice for this kind of task?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Laravel way is:

1. [Create console command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan#writing-commands)
2. [Run scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#defining-schedules)

Command is just a PHP class, so you can use all power of Laravel in it.

Comment: Thank-you so much for pointing me to the awesome direction ! Although, I have 1 question, do I need to add this entry to my cron tasks  `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` - even if I want to automated every 5 minutes ?

Comment: The first field is for Minutes. If you specify * in this field, it runs every minutes. If you specify */5 in the 1st field, it runs every 5 minutes as shown. `*/5 * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @ThomasSnijder : I thought we leave it as is - *as an initial configs*, but when we create the class, we call this function `->everyFiveMinutes();` ??? @Alexey, can you advise ?

Comment: @ihue, yes you should add this entry. It will run Laravel Scheduler every minute. If you want to run task every 5 minutes, use Scheduler's `->everyFiveMinutes()` method for that.

Comment: That what I am getting at as well, when I am reading the docs. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: One last question, will this **task scheduler**, impact the performance of my site, like (loading time) ? Is it run on the back end on it own world somewhere ? I hope it doesn't impact the site performance.

Comment: @ihue, it will not impact site perfomance by itself. However, if you're going to run resource-intensive tasks, consider using queues: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues

Comment: Thank-you very much for your advises today.